# log2 axis doesn't work for histograms in matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

when plotting a histogram using matplotlib/seaborn i would like to change the x-axis to be in log2 scale. the data plotted are [here](http://pastebin.com/GDLM0tQK)

when i take the log2 of values and make a histogram it works, but if i plot the unlogged values and change the x-axis using `set_xscale`, it gives the wrong result. code is:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df = pandas.read_table("data.csv",sep="\t")
plt.figure()
sns.set_style("ticks")
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.hist(df["y"])
ax1.set_xscale("log", basex=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.hist(np.log2(df["y"]))
```

the plot:

[image]

is this a bug or did i change axes incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is neither! See what happens if you increase the number of bins:

```
plt.hist(df["y"], bins = 300)
ax1.set_xscale("log", basex=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.hist(np.log2(df["y"]), bins=300)
```

[image: logbins]

The data for the histogram is the *same*, but the bin size distribution is *still linear* in the top case.

How to make the two cases ideantical? Pass custom bin sizes in log space to `plt.hist`:

```
plt.figure()
sns.set_style("ticks")
ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
logbins = np.logspace(np.log2(df["y"].min()),
                      np.log2(df["y"].max()),
                      300, base=2)
plt.hist(df["y"], bins = logbins)
ax1.set_xscale("log", basex=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.hist(np.log2(df["y"]), bins=300)
```

[image: fixed]

There are still some minor differences between the two plots, but I believe they are not related to your original issue.

Comment: still odd behavior. ggplot2 handles all of this automatically

Comment: I agree, this isn't a very friendly use case.

Comment: @mvd the matplotlib development team will happily review patches submitted to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/

Comment: @VlasSokolov minor clarification: you didn't increase the bin size, but the bin *count* in your first example